# DNS problem dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.smk-stb.ru.': failure

Tags: apache2, dns

[image]
Hello, please tell me I can't configure dns for my domain my static IP is 146.19.113.24 domain smk-stb.ru local IP 192.168.0.105 configured via webmin
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your system set to use that BIND9 server for its DNS or no?  Simply putting a DNS server up for a domain won't make it 'visible', you need to make sure it's in the DNS servers *your system* uses.  It will not resolve for the Internet at large, though, until you put it on public DNS servers with your public IP entry on there.

Comment: I just changed forwarders to google dns I have a public ip 146.19.113.24 in webmin dns it says 127.0.0.53

Comment: No, I'm not asking what your BIND9 server uses for forwarders.  **What DNS server does your computer you're trying to access this site on use?** Does it refer to your DNS server that has this DNS entry?  Is this DNS server publicly reachable from the Internet?  Have you set the domain's NS entries at the domain registrar to point to your DNS server?

Comment: Yes, I have configured NS at the domain registrar. Yes my public IP 146.19.113.24 is accessible from the Internet if you enter it the site will open smk-stb.ru but it will be written unable to connect to the site Please tell me what screenshots I need to make so that you can see, thank you very much

Comment: In the network settings DHCP ipv4 automatically and dns also automatically